# How can I prevent TortoiseSVN from trying to sync deleted folders to a closed repository?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, repository

I have a folder with all of my working copy folders in it.  Most of the working copies are linked to repositories in one account, but one folder went to an old repository on a different account.  I no longer have access to that repository and the linked working copy folder has been removed.  However, TortoiseSVN keeps trying to sync to the bad account.  Is there any way to keep Tortoise from attempting to sync this folder?  If I try to update all of my working copies in the main folder, I get a load of errors because of the missing one.  I have even restored the folder and attempted to deactivate it there, but in the update process, it is still trying to sync it again.

All of these folders are my personal projects and none are used by others, so any and all changes are OK to do without messing anyone else up.

---

**Edit for more info:** 
Terminology overlap might be making this more confusing that it should be. I have one folder `C:\Projects` that I put all my active development stuff in.  The folders within `C:\Projects` are for separate Visual Studio Solutions, each of which might have multiple VS Projects. Each solution folder/working copy is tied to an SVN repository.  Some go to a Subversion Edge account (work) and some to an Assembla account (personal).  Each account has multiple repositories within it, pairing up with each working copy folder within `C:\Projects`.

I used to have a different account for my personal projects, but that is closed.  However, there is still one folder which thinks it is tied to that old account.  If I right click on `C:\Projects` and say update or commit, which would normally cover all changes to any of the working copies, regardless of the account used (Subversion Edge or Assembla).  Instead now I get a bunch of errors because of the closed personal account.  Even deleting the old folder will not stop it from updating because it thinks I need to update the fact that it is deleted.

Comment: It sounds like you have ONE working copy with a bunch of project subfolders, and you no longer have access to one of those projects. Is that what you mean? I.e. when you "update...the main folder" do you just click on the single parent directory and choose update, or do you select all folders inside the main folder first and update all of them that way?

Comment: @Ben Kind of.  See my edit for more info.  This is more an annoyance than a show stopper, because I can update each subfolder separately, but I like being able to do it all at once and I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: If you have "update" and "commit" options on C:/projects, then AFAIK that must also be an svn working copy. Unless there's some sort of configuration to allow that on unversioned folders?